# Почему программа всегда "Неправильно введен день" (Java)

Tags: java, switch

Только учусь... По задумке при наборе числа программа должна выдавать соответствующий день недели.
Но по факту она всегда выдает надпись - "Неправильно введен день".
Что я сделал не так???
Заранее спасибо за ответ

```
import java.io.IOException;

 public class HelloWorld {`введите сюда код`
 public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Введите цифру:");
    char ch;
    String s;
    ch = (char) System.in.read();

        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                s = "Понедельник";
                break;
            case 2:
                s = "Вторник";
                break;
            case 3:
                s = "Среда";
                break;
            case 4:
                s = "Четверг";
                break;
            case 5:
                s = "Пятница";
                break;
            case 6:
                s = "Суббота";
                break;
            case 7:
                s = "Воскресенье";
                break;
            default:
                s = "Неправильно введен день";
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Если считать byte, привести к char, а потом сравнить с int, то результат будет закономерно неправильным.

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел ответ))) Там где case надо цифры в одинарные кавычки брать:
 case '1'
 case '2'
Видимо потому что символьный char у меня